# How to build dynamic Python class with a stub file and method validation

Tags: python

I have a python class where the implementation of every function in the class is the exact same. This is because the main purpose of the class is to build out strings based on function calls.

for example:

```
class StringBuilder:        
    def __init__(self):
        self.previous_strings = []

    @staticmethod
    def _generate_string_builder(previous_string_builder):
        current_frame = inspect.currentframe()
        previous_frame = current_frame.f_back
        function_name = previous_frame.f_code.co_name
        new_string_builder = StringBuilder()
        new_string_builder.previous_strings = previous_string_builder.previous_strings.copy()
        new_string_builder.previous_strings.append(function_name)
        return new_string_builder

    def __str__(self):
        str_rep = ""
        for s in self.previous_strings:
            str_rep = f"{str_rep}.{s}()"
        return str_rep

    def hello(self):
        return StringBuilder._generate_string_builder(self)

    def world(self):
        return StringBuilder._generate_string_builder(self)
```

So with the above code, you should be able to do something like this:

`print(StringBuilder().hello().world())`

and the output would be:
`hello().world()`

hopefully that makes sense so far.

Here is my question.

Is it possible that I could define all the valid function calls in a stub file so that auto complete can pick them up including any arguments they might support. And then for the implementation of StringBuilder I can do something like this:

```
class StringBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.previous_strings = []

    def __get_attr__(self, name):
        if magical_check_is_valid(name):
            return _generate_string_builder(name, self)
        else:
            raise AttributeError(f"No function or attribute {name}")

    @staticmethod
    def _generate_string_builder(function_name, previous_string_builder):
        new_string_builder = StringBuilder()
        new_string_builder.previous_strings = previous_string_builder.previous_strings.copy()
        new_string_builder.previous_strings.append(function_name)
        return new_string_builder

    def __str__(self):
        str_rep = ""
        for s in self.previous_strings:
            str_rep = f"{str_rep}.{s}()"
        return str_rep
```

Where there is a validation to make sure they are calling an accepted function from the stub file, and then execute the string builder logic. any thoughts?

Comment: I'm curious what the purpose of this is. It is possible you're trying to solve some underlying problem (not mentioned here) that can (and should) be solved very differently, because this seems rather odd behaviour for a class.

Comment: "hopefully that makes sense so far." no, not really. This seems completely pointless. Like, you *can* do this, or you know, just write a string-literal directly. This is just a crazy way to do that. Like, I can do `x = [1,3,4,5,6][-2]` if I *want*. But you can just do `x = 5`

Comment: @9769953 I made something similar to this to execute heavily obfuscated (and malicious) java script so I could log the actual function calls being made.

Comment: "Is it possible that I could define all the valid function calls in a stub file so that auto complete can pick them up including any arguments they might support." What do you mean a stub file? Why not define it on the class itself? What is it you are actually trying to achieve? Again, you *can* do that, although, I'm not sure how it will work with static analysis tools, but *why* would you want to do that?

Comment: I am bridging a python library to a javascript library, so I want to make sure to have a valid interface or mapping of calls that can be made, but I want all of those calls to essentially execute the same code, so as to allow a string version of the function to be passed to and then evaluated by the javascript library.

Answer (score 1):

None of your magic seems to be necessary.  This code achieves the same result, generically  However, since this is so simple, I assume this doesn't really solve the overall problem.

```
class StringBuilder:        
    def __init__(self):
        self.previous_strings = []

    def __str__(self):
        return ('().'.join(self.previous_strings)) + '()'

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        self.previous_strings.append( attr )
        return lambda: self

print(StringBuilder().hello().world())
```

Comment: The goal of this code is to serve as a bridge between a python library and a javascript library. I want to have some kind of interface like file of methods that the calls can be validated against. So yes in the above it works against StringBuilder().hello().world(), but I want to make sure we don't allow StringBuilder().goodbye().world() since that's not a valid function for bridging.